# Calculate possible "snake" passwords

Tags: combinatorics

We all know the new password screens on mobile devices. It consists of a matrix of dots, that are to be connected.

A unique password is a vector of points. The points can be connected to themselves with the following restrictions:

- A point can be connected to only 1 other point
- A line will be forced to connect to a closer point if the destination point and the free point are on the same line. An example:

[image]

Since the middle point was not connected before, There was no way to connect the top point to the bottom.

The first restriction makes this a find the number of graphs that are trees. It's the second restriction that I cannot find a way to calculate.

Is there a easier way to calculate the amount of possibilities, or the only way is to generate all possibilities and count them?

Comment: Isn't it infinite?  Or, is there a limit on how many points you can touch..

Comment: @MikeChristensen well, you can't go back to the points you crossed.

Comment: "We all know the new password screens on mobile devices." - I don't. Can you connect any number of points (i.e. all 9)? Can you directly connect the top left one with the middle right one (without the middle point), so essentially the only ones needing middle points are those directly opposite one another? Can lines cross?

Comment: Ah gotcha, so you can't do a square 50 times..

Comment: @Dukeling Yes, you can, the restriction is on the points that lie exactly on the line between two points. Points cannot be repeated, and you can connect any number of points, without repetitions.

Comment: I'd try the math site, bet they've solved this one.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson We love it too here. If at all, cs.stackexchange.com would be the goto place

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/37167/combination-of-smartphones-pattern-password

Comment: "A point can be connected to only 1 other point" - isn't the middle point connected to two points?

Comment: @Dukeling I think he means "connected" in the sense of "moving from to."

Comment: @Dukeling The problem is to count the number of simple paths in the lettuce graph induced by the 3x3 grid (nodes are adjacent if the straight line segment connecting them does not touch any other nodes)

Comment: what do you mean by "connected to only one other point" ? only first and last nodes will be connected to only one point, all internal nodes will connect to two nodes

Comment: @NiklasB. I was looking for a solution for bigger matricies too, I've seen a 5x5 for a bank login.

Comment: @BartlomiejLewandowski That's a more interesting problem then, please update your question accordingly :)

Comment: ok, we'll give you the solution. But first, please tell us which banks and who's phones you are planning to use it on.

Comment: @mangusta yes, you are correct, גלעד ברקן is correct about the moving too part

Comment: @BartlomiejLewandowski the first restriction does not imply any kind of tree. trees with only a single child per node are implied here

Comment: @גלעדברקן I'm just interested in the amount of possibilites. Why they decided for a 5x5 and not something bigger.

Comment: In the math answer, there is a reference to a Wikipedia entry about self-avoiding walks, indicating that "Finding the number of such paths is conjectured to be an NP-hard problem." http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-avoiding_walk

Comment: Ignoring point #2, the number of 5x5 combinations doesn't fit in a 64bit unsigned number.  That's many more bits than expected!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since the general problem of counting [simple paths](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_%28graph_theory%29#Different_types_of_paths) in an undirected graph is [#P-complete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sharp-P-complete), and as was pointed out in the comments, the similar problem of counting [self-avoiding paths in a grid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-avoiding_walk) is conjectured to be hard, I think it is appropriate to think about how we can solve the problem in o((n*n)!) time (with n=3 in your case).

We have to keep in mind an additional special case that usually applies on "real" smartphones:

- We *can* go across intermediate nodes, if those have already been visited. For example it is usually possible to go (0,0) -> (1,1) -> (0,2) -> (2,0)

There is a simple dynamic programming approach that should be able to solve at least up to the 5x5 case: Let *f(i,j,visited)* be the number of ways when we are currently at vertex (i,j) and `visited` is the set of nodes we visited earlier. We can compute *f* using dynamic programming by trying all possible moves and recursing. We can represent `visited` as a bitmask. The total number of possibilities will then be `sum(i,j, f(i,j, {(i,j)}))`.

Here are the results:

```
n = 2     64
n = 3     389497
n = 4     4350069824956
n = 5     236058362078882840752465
```

Seems to be pretty secure from a information-theoretical standpoint even for n = 4.

Below is the C++ implementation I used. Since the result can be pretty large, the program computes it modulo some large primes, so that we can reconstruct the solution using the Chinese Remainder Theorem.

```cpp
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <cassert>
using namespace std;

typedef long long ll;

const int n = 5;
bool getbit(int visited, int i, int j) { return visited & (1<<(i*n + j)); }
int setbit(int visited, int i, int j) { return visited | (1<<(i*n + j)); }
bool inrange(int i) { return 0 <= i && i < n; }
short dp[n][n][1<<(n*n)];
int mod;
int f(int i, int j, int visited) {
    short& res = dp[i][j][visited];
    if (res != -1) return res;
    res = 1;
    for (int di = -i; di <= n-i-1; ++di)
        for (int dj = -j; dj <= n-j-1; ++dj) {
            if ((di == 0 && dj == 0) || abs(__gcd(di, dj)) != 1) continue;
            int i2 = i + di, j2 = j + dj;
            while (inrange(i2) && inrange(j2) && getbit(visited, i2, j2)) {
                i2 += di;
                j2 += dj;
            }
            if (inrange(i2) && inrange(j2)) {
                res += f(i2, j2, setbit(visited, i2, j2));
                if (res >= mod) res -= mod;
            }
        }
    return res;
}

int primes[] = {
    15013,
    15017,
    15031,
    15053,
    15061,
    15073,
    15077,
    15083,
    15091,
    15101,
};

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int lo = 0;
    int hi = sizeof primes / sizeof *primes - 1;
    if (argc > 1) {
        stringstream ss; ss << argv[1]; ss >> lo;
        hi = lo;
    }
    for (int p = lo; p <= hi; ++p) {
        mod = primes[p];
        cout << mod << " " << flush;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
            for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j)
                for (ll m = 0; m < (1<<(n*n)); ++m)
                    dp[i][j][m] = -1;
        ll answer = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
            for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j)
                answer = (answer + f(i, j, setbit(0, i, j))) % mod;
        cout << answer << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: There, wrote a program that calculates upper-limits: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6167d2ce5de40b07.  3x3->986409, 4x4->56874039553216, and 5x5 doesn't fit in a `unsigned long long`.