# 4 by 3 lock pattern

Tags: c++, algorithm, combinations, permutation

I came across this [problem](https://icpcarchive.ecs.baylor.edu/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&page=show_problem&problem=4334).

which asks to calculate the number of ways a lock pattern of a specific length can be made in 4x3 grid and follows the rules. **there may be some of the points must not be included in the path**

A valid pattern has the following properties:

- A pattern can be represented using the sequence of points which it's touching for the first time (in the same order of drawing the pattern), a pattern going from (1,1) to (2,2) is not the same as a pattern going from (2,2) to (1,1).
- For every two consecutive points A and B in the pattern representation, if the line segment connecting A and B passes through some other points, these points must be in the sequence also and comes before A and B, otherwise the pattern will be invalid. For example a pattern representation which starts with (3,1) then (1,3) is invalid because the segment passes through (2,2) which didn't appear in the pattern representation before (3,1), and the correct representation for this pattern is (3,1) (2,2) (1,3). But the pattern (2,2) (3,2) (3,1) (1,3) is valid because (2,2) appeared before (3,1).
- In the pattern representation we don't mention the same point more than once, even if the pattern will touch this point again through another valid segment, and each segment in the pattern must be going from a point to another point which the pattern didn't touch before and it might go through some points which already appeared in the pattern.
- The length of a pattern is the sum of the Manhattan distances between every two consecutive points in the pattern representation. The Manhattan distance between two points (X1, Y1) and (X2, Y2) is |X1 - X2| + |Y1 - Y2| (where |X| means the absolute value of X).
- A pattern must touch at least two points

my approach was a brute force, loop over the points, start at the point and using recursive decremente the length until reach a length zero then add 1 to the number of combinations.

Is there a way to calculate it in mathematical equation or there is a better algorithm for this ?

**UPDATE:**
here is what I have done, it gives some wrong answers ! I think the problem is in `isOk` function ! 
`notAllowed` is a global bit mask of the not allowed points.

```
bool isOk(int i, int j, int di,int dj, ll visited){
    int mini = (i<di)?i:di;
    int minj = (j<dj)?j:dj;

    if(abs(i-di) == 2 && abs(j-dj) == 2 && !getbit(visited, mini+1, minj+1) )
        return false;
    if(di == i && abs(j - dj) == 2 && !getbit(visited, i,minj+1) )
        return false;
    if(di == i && abs(j-dj) == 3 && (!getbit(visited, i,1) || !getbit(visited, i,2)) )
        return false;
    if(dj == j && abs(i - di) == 2 && !getbit(visited, 1,j) )
        return false;

    return true;
}

int f(int i, int j, ll visited, int l){
    if(l > L) return 0;
    short& res = dp[i][j][visited][l];
    if(res != -1) return res;
    res = 0;
    if(l == L) return ++res;

    for(int di=0 ; di<gN ; ++di){
        for(int dj=0 ; dj<gM ; ++dj){
            if( getbit(notAllowed, di, dj) || getbit(visited, di, dj) || !isOk(i,j, di,dj,  visited) )
                continue;
            res += f(di, dj, setbit(visited, di, dj), l+dist(i,j , di,dj));
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[My answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22621174/calculate-possible-snake-passwords/22622326#22622326) can be adapted to this problem as well.

Let *f(i,j,visited,k)* the number of ways to complete a partial pattern, when we are currently at node (i,j), have already visited the vertices in the set *visited* and have so far walked a path length of *k*. We can represent *visited* as a bitmask.

We can compute *f(i,j,visited,k)* recursively by trying all possible next moves and apply DP to reuse subproblem solutions:

> f(i,j, visited, L) = 1
>
> f(i,j, visited, k) = 0  if k > L
>
> f(i,j, visited, k) = sum(possible moves (i', j'): f(i', j', visited UNION {(i',j')}, k + dis((i,j), (i',j')))

Possible moves are those that cross a number of visited vertices and then end in an univisited (and not forbidden) one.

If *D* is the set of forbidden vertices, the answer to the question is

> sum((i,j) not in D: f(i,j, {(i,j)}, L)).

The runtime is something like O(X^2 * Y^2 * 2^(X*Y) * maximum possible length). I guess the maximum possible length is in fact well below *1000*.

**UPDATE:** I implemented this solution and it got accepted. I enumerated the possible moves in the following way: Assume we are at point (i,j) and have already visited the set of vertices *visited*. Enumerate all distinct coprime pairs (dx,dy) 0 <= dx < X and 0 <= dy < Y. Then find the smallest k with P_k = (i + k*dx, j + k*dy) still being a valid grid point and P_k not in *visited*. If P_k is not forbidden, it is a valid move.

The maximum possible path length is 39.

I'm using a DP array of size 3 * 4 * 2^12 * 40 to store the subproblem results.

Comment: can you explain the algorithm more, or provide pesudo code ?

Comment: @Rami the other answer contains actual C++ code. The only difference is the length parameter

Comment: Niklas B, I'm still learning DP, I've tried to adapt the algorithm for this problem but I couldn't, could you help me?

Comment: @RamiJarrar I can answer questions and clarify my answer, yes. So please ask ahead (but please don't ask for code). It can't hurt doing some simpler tasks with DP on bitmasks first

Comment: ok, can you explain the algorithm behind the f(i,j,visited, L) more ?

Comment: @RamiJarrar I added the explicit recurrence. Can you maybe be specific about what you don't understand about the definition "the number of ways to complete a partial pattern with a suffix of size L, when we are currently at node (i,j) and can't visit the vertices in the set visited anymore"?

Comment: @RamiJarrar I implemented the solution. I can share the code if you want, but I understand if you don't want to be spoilered

Comment: @Rami rethink the cases where di < i or dj < j. It's not really elegant to hardcode all the checks by the way, you should try to generalize that to avoid errors

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of attributes of the combinations that may be used to optimize the brute force method:

1. Using mirror images (horizontal, vertical, or both) you can generate 4 combinations for each one found (except horizontal or vertical lines). Maybe you could consider only combinations starting in one quadrant.
2. You can usually generate additional combinations of the same length by translation (moving a combination).

Comment: ok,, but there may be some of the points not included in the path, this breaks the mirror ? can you explain more !