# All possible lock combinations in android of length 5

Tags: java, algorithm

I recently came across a an interview question which was like this:

"Generate all possible lock combinations on an android lock screen of length 5 such that each numbers are adjacent to each other and no repetitions within a combination"

I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6979524/android-lock-password-combinations) question which is similar to current question but with minor change in length but the solution given was more of mathematical rather than programming. I am having trouble in formulating the way into a program(or at least an algorithm). Can anyone help me in this?

Comment: Please explain exactly the constraints that the lock screen uses.

Comment: Is this lock screen a password one (using numbers/letters) or a bullet one (where you have to connect bullets/dots to unlock)?

Comment: I've written several answers about similar questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22621174/calculate-possible-snake-passwords/22622326#22622326  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23113290/4-by-3-lock-pattern/23115300#23115300 the general ideas in there should be helpful. The second incorporates a length restriction

Comment: It's an android screen pattern lock and the constraint is that each number or say each point in the grid path should be adjacent

Comment: @user2966197: "It's an android screen pattern lock" IMAGINE IF I DIDN'T HAVE AN ANDROID PHONE

Comment: @j_random_hacker BUT EVERYBODY HAS ONE

Comment: @j_random_hacker it's kind of a rhetorical question. The question says that it's for android password. Also even if you don't consider the pattern generator, i don't think it will affect much as the question says that the numbers should be adjacent.So, even if you replace the dots with the corresponding numbers like in a dialpad, the situation will remain same

Comment: @user2966197 Well, how many columns and rows are there?

Comment: @ArtjomB. just like a password lock screen, it will have 3 rows and 3 columns

Comment: @user2966197: My point was that I, and probably many others, don't know what an Android password lock screen looks like.  I can guess, or I can find the answer by Googling, but should I really have to do either of those things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a Graph such that all the numbers that are adjacent to each other in the keypad are connected in the graph. Then the problem boils down to traversing the Graph in Depth First search manner till level 5 (consider only unvisited nodes(buttons)).